# Can we have variable keys defined inside a hash?

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to create a hash as follows :

```
my $block_name = pm88_60_464 ;    
my %hash_for_tstamp = qw (
         layout/${block_name}.proj/tech  ap_db_time
         rpts/sem_check/sem_check_analysis.rpt  sem_analysis
  );

my $key;
my $value;

while (($key,$value) = each (%hash_for_tstamp)) {    
  ${$time_summary}{"$value"} = ctime(stat($key)->mtime) ;    
}
```

While running above code i am getting below error.

```
stat() on unopened filehandle File::stat::layout/${block_name}.proj/tech .
Can't call method "mtime" on an undefined value at audit_automation.pl line 205.
```

So what i've understood by this error is that we are allowed to have variable keys inside hash.

Comment: The issue is that there's no variable interpolation inside of a `qw//` quote-like construct.  Use a comma-separated list, and double quotes where necessary for individual components, instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So what you mean to say is if i'll not define my hash through qw then it should work ?

Comment: Yes, instead of `qw/....../`, use `( "....", "...." )`

Comment: I tried that way also but it's not working. I think defining through qw or otherwise doesn't matter.

Comment: You'll have to edit your post, adding a second section of code demonstrating your use of `("...","...")`, then, because for me, that clears it right up.

Comment: sorry David, it's working fine. Previously i defined it using single quotes which didn't work.

Comment: Great. So you have an answer you can accept, then. :)  Glad it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is one of variable interpolation, or the lack thereof when using the `qw//` construct.  There is no variable interpolation inside of `qw//`, as is explained in [perlop Quote and Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

You can resolve the situation by using the appropriate quote-like construct; in this case, double-quotes where variable interpolation is desired.  Here's an example:

```
my $block_name = "pm88_60_464";    
my %hash_for_tstamp = (
    "layout/${block_name}.proj/tech",        "ap_db_time",
    "rpts/sem_check/sem_check_analysis.rpt", "sem_analysis"
);


while ( my ($key,$value) = each (%hash_for_tstamp) ) {    
  print "($key),($value)\n";
}
```